# In Qt, how to determine if the webpage's email or print icon has been clicked using QWebView?

Tags: qt, email, printing

I am loading a page using QWebView. How can I found out if the webpage's email icon or the print icon has been clicked ? The pageAction() function doesn't return any such constant.

Answer (score 0):

every icon in the View will emit the linkClicked signal.

void    linkClicked ( const QUrl & url )

Comment: Thanks. But the print and email icons don't emit this signal if u click on them, though other hyperlinks do (perhaps because they are javascript commands). How to read javascript commands like these.                        There is a printRequested signal, but there is no signal for email requests.